# Simple button as3

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi i m trying to implement a simple button on my as3.
but this is not working.

i just added bouton1 to my scene but when i click on it nothing happen ( trace function doesnt show my message

this is my code

```
package {

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;






//import org.papervision3d.core.animation.clip.AnimationClip3D;
import org.papervision3d.objects.parsers.DAE;
//import org.papervision3d.objects.parsers.Max3DS;
//import org.papervision3d.objects.parsers.KMZ;
import org.papervision3d.view.BasicView;    
import org.papervision3d.events.FileLoadEvent;
import org.papervision3d.objects.DisplayObject3D;
import org.papervision3d.view.BasicView;

//added color to objects
import org.papervision3d.materials.ColorMaterial;
import org.papervision3d.materials.utils.MaterialsList;

import org.papervision3d.core.math.Matrix3D;
import org.papervision3d.core.math.Number3D;
import org.papervision3d.lights.PointLight3D;

public class ExternalModelsExample extends BasicView

{
    private static const FORWARD:Number3D = new Number3D(0, 0, 1);
    private var model:DisplayObject3D;
    private var model2:DisplayObject3D;
    private var model3:DisplayObject3D;/*
    private var model4:DisplayObject3D;
    private var model5:DisplayObject3D;
    private var model6:DisplayObject3D;
    private var model7:DisplayObject3D;
    private var model8:DisplayObject3D;
    private var model9:DisplayObject3D;
    private var model10:DisplayObject3D;*/
    private var rotX:Number = 0.2;
    private var rotY:Number = 0.2;
    private var camPitch:Number = 90;
    private var camYaw:Number = 270;
    private var easeOut:Number = 0.1;


    // definition de la propriété couleur
    private var color:ColorMaterial;
    private var color2:ColorMaterial;
    private var color3:ColorMaterial;/*
    private var color4:ColorMaterial;
    private var color5:ColorMaterial;
    private var color6:ColorMaterial;
    private var color7:ColorMaterial;
    private var color8:ColorMaterial;
    private var color9:ColorMaterial;
    private var color10:ColorMaterial;*/

    private var previousMousePoint:Point = new Point();
    private var isMouseDown:Boolean = false;

    var bouton1:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();




    public function ExternalModelsExample()
    {   
        stage.frameRate = 40;
        init();
        startRendering();
        addChild(bouton1);
        bouton1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, test);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, stage_mouseDownHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_mouseUpHandler);




    }
    public function test(){
        trace("test");
    }


    private function init():void
    {




        //Declaration color material
        color = new ColorMaterial(0x65b5ff);
        color2 = new ColorMaterial(0xffffff);
        color3 = new ColorMaterial(0x757575);/*
        color4 = new ColorMaterial(0x65b5ff);
        color5 = new ColorMaterial(0xffffff);
        color6 = new ColorMaterial(0x874630);
        color7 = new ColorMaterial(0xbe0da7);
        color8 = new ColorMaterial(0x3107bb);
        color9 = new ColorMaterial(0xff4448);
        color10 = new ColorMaterial(0xc7c7c7);*/


        //COLLADA Utah Teapot
        //Add import on top: import org.papervision3d.objects.parsers.DAE;
        model = new DAE();
        model.addEventListener(FileLoadEvent.LOAD_COMPLETE,modelLoaded);
        DAE(model).load("assets/Z1.DAE", new MaterialsList ( { all:color } ));
        model2 = new DAE();
        model2.addEventListener(FileLoadEvent.LOAD_COMPLETE,modelLoaded);
        DAE(model2).load("assets/Z2.DAE", new MaterialsList ( { all:color2 } ));
        model3 = new DAE();
        model3.addEventListener(FileLoadEvent.LOAD_COMPLETE,modelLoaded);
        DAE(model3).load("assets/Z3.DAE", new MaterialsList ( { all:color3 } ));
        /*model = new DAE();
        model.addEventListener(FileLoadEvent.LOAD_COMPLETE,modelLoaded);
        DAE(model).load("assets/Z4.DAE", new MaterialsList ( { all:color } ));
        model2 = new DAE();
        model2.addEventListener(FileLoadEvent.LOAD_COMPLETE,modelLoaded);
        DAE(model2).load("assets/Z5.DAE", new MaterialsList ( { all:color2 } ));
        model3 = new DAE();
        model3.addEventListener(FileLoadEvent.LOAD_COMPLETE,modelLoaded);
        DAE(model3).load("assets/Z6.DAE", new MaterialsList ( { all:color3 } ));
        model = new DAE();
        model.addEventListener(FileLoadEvent.LOAD_COMPLETE,modelLoaded);
        DAE(model).load("assets/Z7.DAE", new MaterialsList ( { all:color } ));
        model2 = new DAE();
        model2.addEventListener(FileLoadEvent.LOAD_COMPLETE,modelLoaded);
        DAE(model2).load("assets/Z9.DAE", new MaterialsList ( { all:color2 } ));
        model3 = new DAE();
        model3.addEventListener(FileLoadEvent.LOAD_COMPLETE,modelLoaded);
        DAE(model3).load("assets/Z12-cockpit.DAE", new MaterialsList ( { all:color3 } ));
        model = new DAE();
        model.addEventListener(FileLoadEvent.LOAD_COMPLETE,modelLoaded);
        DAE(model).load("assets/Z13-barres.DAE", new MaterialsList ( { all:color } ));*/



    }

    private function modelLoaded(e:FileLoadEvent):void
    {

        scene.addChild(model);
        scene.addChild(model2);
        scene.addChild(model3);/*
        scene.addChild(model4);
        scene.addChild(model5);
        scene.addChild(model6);
        scene.addChild(model7);
        scene.addChild(model8);
        scene.addChild(model9);
        scene.addChild(model10);*/

    }




    private function stage_mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        isMouseDown = true;
    }

    private function stage_mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        isMouseDown = false;    
    }


    override protected function onRenderTick(e:Event=null):void
    {   

        var currentMousePoint:Point = new Point(viewport.containerSprite.mouseX, viewport.containerSprite.mouseY);

        if(isMouseDown)
        {
            var difference:Point = currentMousePoint.subtract(previousMousePoint);
            var vector:Number3D = new Number3D(difference.x, difference.y, 0);
            var rotationAxis:Number3D = Number3D.cross(vector, FORWARD);
            rotationAxis.normalize();
            var distance:Number = Point.distance(currentMousePoint, previousMousePoint);
            var rotationMatrix:Matrix3D = Matrix3D.rotationMatrix(rotationAxis.x, -rotationAxis.y, rotationAxis.z, distance/250);

            model.transform.calculateMultiply3x3(rotationMatrix, model.transform);
            model2.transform.calculateMultiply3x3(rotationMatrix, model2.transform);
            model3.transform.calculateMultiply3x3(rotationMatrix, model2.transform);
        }

        previousMousePoint = currentMousePoint;
        super.onRenderTick();
    }

}
```

}

di you know why my trace("test"), doesn t work ??

there is a conflict with the object drag ?

flash doesn t show error

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SimpleButton object is more complex than just "add and forget", you need to fill its properties, which is normally done at design time. There are four DisplayObject type objects, namely `upState, overState, downState, hitTestState` that determine the shape and contents of that button. In order to make a button visible and hittable, you need to specify 4 Sprites (or other DisplayObjects) as parameters to SimpleButton constructor. The `hitTestState` object is used to capture events, and is always invisible, so you just need to draw a correct shape on it. Other states are visible when the button is up, when the mouse is over a button, and when the mouse is pressed on the button respectively.

```
var upSprite:Sprite=new Sprite();
upSprite.graphics.lineStyle(2,0,1);
upSprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,20);
var hitSprite:Shape=new Shape();
hitSprite.graphics.beginFill(0,1);
hitSprite.graphics.drawRect(3,3,44,14); // a bit smaller rect to make the button narrow
var bouton1:SimpleButton=new SimpleButton(upSprite,upSprite,upSprite,hitSprite);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. try the trace action on mouse_down not click.
2. you have mentioned if(isMouseDown) in last lines. I'm sorry if this is wrong, but havnt u got to say like if(isMouseDown) = true